# Reordering a list to maximize difference of adjacent elements

Tags: python, algorithm, permutation

I'm interested in reordering a list in such a manner as to maximize the sum of the squares of the differences between adjacent elements (cyclic). Here is a piece of Python code that brute-forces the solution in factorial time, so you can see what I mean:

```
def maximal_difference_reorder(input):

   from itertools import permutations

   best_sum = 0
   best_orderings = []

   for x in permutations(input):
        d = np.sum(np.diff(x)**2) + (x[0] - x[-1])**2
        if d > best_sum:
            best_orderings = [x]
            best_sum = d
        elif d == best_sum:
            best_orderings.append(x)

   return best_orderings
```

This yields the following results for `maximal_difference_reorder(range(4))`:

```
[(0, 2, 1, 3),
 (0, 3, 1, 2),
 (1, 2, 0, 3),
 (1, 3, 0, 2),
 (2, 0, 3, 1),
 (2, 1, 3, 0),
 (3, 0, 2, 1),
 (3, 1, 2, 0)]
```

As you can see, all the results are cyclic rotations and reflections of each other. If the score was determined with the sum of the differences, not squared, I believe all permutations would be evenly scored, given an evenly-spaced input.

Brute forcing works well, but O(n!) is terrible, so is it possible to do this in a smaller asymptotic computational time? Bonus points if it works for an uneven input mesh, or for other scoring functions.

Incidentally, this isn't homework or an interview question, though perhaps it would make a good one. Rather, I'm trying to generate a spectrum of colours for a series of parameterised data, and I'm trying to avoid having similar colours next to each other.

Comment: Isn't a maximal squared difference guaranteed for range(n) by the sequence 0, n-1, 1, n-2, 2, n-3, ...? e.g. your 0,3,1,2 sequence, e.g. 0,4,1,3,2 for range(5), etc.

Comment: I think he talking about a list of random numbers.Like  [n, 2n+1, 35n+4 , x , y ... ].

Comment: @barny: nope, consider the chain 0,4,5,6,6. Then you will get a score of 66, with the maximum being 77 actually. The question being whether to dipserse around the biggest or the smallest number

Comment: oh well if you can repeat/omit numbers that is different... I said I was  referring to range(n), like you used in your example.

Comment: @barny yes, that's true for evenly spaced numbers, for the sum of the squared differences. Is it true for other scoring functions (eg: `sqrt(abs(x -y))`)? And is there a general algorithm for unevenly spaced (but sorted) lists? It seems like a generally useful tool to have.

Comment: Since you're working with a cycle of numbers, I'd recommend just defining a canonical form to avoid showing all rotations & reflections. Smallest number first, next largest second, etc... if there's a tie.

Comment: If you can't solve a problem, try solving a simpler problem. How about the non-cyclic version of this problem?

Comment: How about the greedy algorithm? At each step, prepend or append the number to increase the score the most (this will make a zigzag wave of increasing then decreasing amplitude). Try that starting with either the smallest number or largest number.

Answer (score 4):

Your problem is a slightly disguised instance of the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem).

Call the input list `c` (for "cities"). Pick any `M` which is an upper bound on `(c[i]-c[j])**2` This is easily done in linear time since the min and the max of the list can be computed in a single pass, in which case `M = (max - min)**2` works. Define the distance, `d[i,j]` from `c[i]` to `c[j]` by:

```
d(i,j) = 0 if i == j else M - (c[i]-c[j])**2
```

It is easy to see that for any cyclic permutation the cost of that permutation (computed according to `d`) is `n*M - sum of squares of differences` hence it is minimized if and only the sum of the squares of the differences is maximized.

There are a wealth of approaches to solving a TSP. Even though it is NP-hard, in practice state-of-the art methods are phenomenally good at solving problems that arise in practice. Furthermore, good heuristic methods can typically get to within a fraction of a percent of optimal.

Your particular problem is a special case of a TSP. As such it is possible that this special case is easier and in fact has a polynomial time solution, but I doubt it. I conjecture that it is NP-hard as well but don't have a proof. Also -- even if it is NP-hard, it might be that there is a solution (perhaps an Integer Programming formulation) which is more efficient than reducing it to TSP as above.

On Edit: based on comments by Dave Gavin and the answer by @SergeBallesta I now think that a polynomial time algorithm is possible. I'll leave this answer up, if for no other reason than if a polynomial time algorithm works then this problem would be a nice example for showing that certain subclasses of the TSP have simpler solutions.

Comment: This was accepted too quickly. Everything John said is true, but the distances we're using for the TSP relate to each other in a special way not typical of a TSP. I'm not saying John is wrong, but it isn't obvious that he's right, and leaving the question open longer would make others likelier to weigh in.

Comment: @DaveGalvin I agree completely -- hence my final paragraph. I wouldn't mind if OP un-accepts my answer (at least for the time being). I'll even edit my post to make this clear.

Comment: Now I'm somewhat embarrassed that I didn't recognise it as a TSP. It might be relatively easy to see if some of the TSP heuristic solvers happen to exactly solve this variant.

Comment: @JohnColeman Say our goal were to minimize the absolute value of differences of the cycle. You could also view that as a TSP, but a simple sort gets the answer.

Comment: @Widjet The reduction to TSP isn't completely obvious. I spent about 15 minutes thinking about heuristic approaches before I realized that I was reinventing the wheel. Also Dave Galvin might be right that the TSP approach isn't the best way.

Comment: @DaveGalvin Good point, although OP is trying to maximize rather than minimize, and the fact that they are asking about circular permutations rather than just permutations raises a nuance that a simple sort doesn't obviously address, even in the case of minimizing the absolute value of the differences -- you have to consider the return edge.

Comment: My instinct is that starting with the min, surrounding it with the two remaining maxes, surrounding that with the two remaining mins, etc... will be optimal, but I can't spend more time on this at present.

Comment: @JohnColeman I am considering the return edge, but still claim that sorting solves it. I'm not saying that this is analogous to the OP's problem, but just that for specially chosen numbers the TSP might not be a useful lens for viewing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to maximize the squares of the differences between consecutive elements in a cyclic way, I would say that you should try to have the biggest element near to the smallest because conceptually `a²+b²>=2*((a+b)/2)²`. That's what you have found by brute force with `range(4)`.

I think that it could be shown by induction, but that part should be better asked on [Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/) but I would bet a coin that the solution is simply to:

- sort the list
- take biggest element put it in index 0 of result list
- take smallest one and put it on index 1
- take smallest of remaining and put it on index -1
- take biggest of remaining and put it on index 2

and iterate one time to the right and one to the left alternating biggest and smallest of remaining elements

You end in:

- O(n * log(n)) statistic for the sort with quicksort or merge-sort, or O(n²/2) with a mere bubble sort
- linear for building the result array

Comment: Looks promising, though I suspect that it is a little more subtle than that.

Comment: Can you please dry run your approach on a higher dimension? I think your approach is to simplistic and am unable to get a correct result for range(10)

Answer (score 1):

I think we can have an O(n) solution

The key to solve this problem is to generate the first seed for the cyclic group. Considering we should be pairing the elements wherein the pairwise square difference sum is maximum which is possible if we pair an element with its farthest neighbor.

Which means if h<sub>i</sub> is the i<sup>th</sup> highest number, then the neighbors of  h<sub>i</sub> are (h<sub>n-i-1</sub>, h<sub>n-i+1</sub>). As the sequence is cyclic so the numbers would wrap around for negative index i.e. h<sub>-1</sub> = h<sub>0</sub>
This will generate the first seed list as  `[0, 6, 2, 4, 3, 5, 1, 7]`

This sequence can easily be generating by swapping every odd index pair i.e. [(a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>n-1</sub>), (a<sub>3</sub>, a<sub>n-3</sub>),...]

The subsequent sequence can be generated by generating a singular sequential rotation and then reflecting the rotated sequence

Here is a sample implementation

```
def maximal_difference_reorder1(x):
    def maximal_difference_seeder(x):
        for i in range(1, len(x) / 2):
            x[i:len(x) - i] = x[i:len(x) - i][::-1]
        return x
    def rotate_left(x):
        start = x
        while True:
            x = x[1:] + x[0:1]
            if x == start: break
            yield x

    x = maximal_difference_seeder(x)
    rotated = [x] + (list(rotate_left(x)) if len(x) > 1 else [])
    reflected = [e[::-1] for e in rotated] if len(x) > 2 else []
    return map(tuple, rotated + reflected)
```

**Sample Run**

```
def display(lst, width = 80):
    it_lst = iter(lst)
    try:
        print '[',
        while True:
            for _ in range(80/(len(lst[0])*3 + 2)):
                print "{},".format(next(it_lst)), 
            print '\n ',
    except StopIteration:
        print ']'

display(maximal_difference_reorder1(range(10)))

[ (0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9), (8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 0), 
  (2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 0, 8), (6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2), 
  (4, 5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 6), (5, 3, 7, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4), 
  (3, 7, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5), (7, 1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3), 
  (1, 9, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7), (9, 0, 8, 2, 6, 4, 5, 3, 7, 1), 
  (9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0), (0, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8), 
  (8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2), (2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6), 
  (6, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5, 4), (4, 6, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 3, 5), 
  (5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7, 3), (3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1, 7), 
  (7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0, 9, 1), (1, 7, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 8, 0, 9), 
  ]
```

**Note** It is assumed that the data is sorted. If not, it is trivial to sort it wherein the solution complexity would be O(nlog n)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the greedy algorithm I suggested in the comments:

> How about the greedy algorithm? At each step, prepend or append the number to increase the score the most (this will make a zigzag wave of increasing then decreasing amplitude). Try that starting with either the smallest number or largest number

It would be interesting to study example where greedy algorithm is not optimal

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34154324/reordering-a-list-to-maximize-difference-of-adjacent-elements?s=2|0.0000
import itertools

def score(x):
    return sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(x, x[1:]))

assert score([0, 2, 5]) == 4 + 9

def maximise(x):
    x = sorted(x)
    candidates = [greedy(x[:1], x[1:]), greedy(x[-1:], x[:-1])]
    return max(candidates, key=score)

def greedy(current, remaining):
    while remaining:
        i, j = max(itertools.product((0, -1), repeat=2), key=lambda pair: score((current[pair[0]], remaining[pair[1]])))
        current.insert(i, remaining.pop(j))

    return current

def cyclic_score(x):
    return sum((a-b)**2 for a,b in zip(x, x[1:] + x[:1]))

assert cyclic_score([0, 2, 5]) == 4 + 9 + 25
```